# How can I get wood in a desert?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to get some wood so I can make chests and crafting tables in my desert biome. The problem is that I can't explore to new biomes because I don't want to leave the village settlement that I would leave behind. The second problem to leaving is that I would have to cross an ocean to get to a new biome. So, how can I collect either wood or planks to have enough materials to have the necessary sticks and chests to survive?

Comment: In a desert biome, it's pretty hard to get started. You have to find the nearest non-desert biome to get anything done.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Odd. Why do you want to make chests, anyway? Do you want to know how to make chests, or how to get wood?

Comment: @avestar101 I want to know how to make chests.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Why, do you need to store items?

Comment: I wanted a super-flat world so I didn't have to deal with mountainous terrain for my horses.

Comment: You accepted the wrong answer. SF's is the correct one: Look in the abandoned mineshafts.

Comment: S.F is correct I just didn't see it.

Comment: Suggest you rename this to "How can I get wood in the desert?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you play this as a challenge - no other biomes, just surviving in the desert:

As of 1.9 dead bushes when broken drop sticks. This makes the challenge much easier than before.

Seek caves (may take some trial and error; some may be buried under the sand) and try to find an abandoned mine. There's wood aplenty in there, in the form of the supports. Some smart creeper management can earn you cobble and coal. Some village houses contain crafting benches you can then use to assemble stone tools without access to wood.

Edit:

[Desert hell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9OYl_xK0IY) was a challenge stream of gameplay in a desert world, with no mineshafts, villages, and caverns. You may watch it for some very creative solutions:

- Wood is still obtainable from Strongholds - but locating one takes enormous effort.
- Dead bushes and witches are important sources of *sticks*. These are a very important resource.
- Cacti are good as a makeshift weapon if you lure the mobs to walk onto them.
- Suffocating mobs is a good way of killing them; there are some ways demonstrated to do this.
- Temples and Dungeons were very important - especially allowing you to get a bucket. Bucket of lava is a mighty weapon.
- Using spider webs you can create wool, which then you can set on fire using lava, to start a nether portal (which you can cast from lava and water obtained from a desert well).

Answer (score 15):

Officially, you can't. Just run in one direction till you find another biome with trees.

Comment: So what's the point of a super flat desert biome?

Comment: @YoungGuilo [Desert Temples](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Desert_Temple) if you mean just a desert biome in a regular world. If you mean a superflat world that's set to generate sand, then probably just for creative-mode building.

Comment: Not every biome was designed with the consideration of how well it will support chest creation in mind.

Comment: @Young The *point* of anything in Minecraft is to do whatever you like. The *usefulness* of a superflat desert world is pretty limited except in Creative. Don't make a superflat desert world if you don't want a superflat desert world.

Comment: Actually superflat desert is very useful - for Creative mode. Doesn't spawn the annoying jelly cubes, doesn't obstruct construction with grass, keeps random animals to minimum - excellent for building stuff without distractions.

Comment: @SF. I've never actually thought of that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 11):

While it is true that there are no trees in desert biomes, I would recommend you find the nearest biome that actually has trees; although there are some workarounds.

If you are lucky enough, you may be able to stumble across an [NPC village](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village), or a [Desert Temple](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Desert_Temple); which may contain actuall chests and or wood to provide for manually making them.

Answer (score 2):

Keep going until you find a tree and cut it down. Then take the saplings and a load of dirt and start a tree farm back in the desert.

Answer (score 1):

You can harvest wood from an Abandoned Mineshaft, which you can find by simply strip-mining the area.

Comment: I'm not too sure how useful this is since it's difficult (and on most maps, probably impossible) to strip mine without any tools; you'll have to look for caverns or hope you happen upon a huge gravel pit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually, using the very rare find of a mineshaft, you CAN turn the wood to sticks. If you can find a piece of dirt, villages might have a  oak sapling. Any other way is /give @p wood_planks 64.

Answer (score 0):

if you are set on a desert biome, you can also just pick bonus chest, then use what little supplies that gets you to get started. of course this could be called cheating, but really if you want to try to survive in a desert biome, without a bonus chest it's nearly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

From [an anonymous suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/319341):

> You actually surprisingly can! Just get dirt and find a wandering trader to give you saplings, and then plant your saplings on the dirt to acquire wood.